# How to ping a mapped drive

Tags: c#

Hello I'm writing an application where the user can enter a directory for storing some files.

In case he entered a directory on the mashine the program is running on, I can just use the path he entered.

In case he entered a directory on the network like this: 192.168.xxx.xxx...,
I can ping and if pingable use this path.

But what if the user has a mapped drive and enteres something like Y:\work... ? The .Net Ping class has a Send method, I'm using it like this:

```
try{
    Ping pinger = new Ping();
    PingReply reply = pinger.Send(NetworkIP);
} catch (PingException) {
    // Discard PingExceptions and return false;
}
```

But if the NetworkIP is Y:\ or something it throws a PingException even if the drive should be available.

Does anybody know how I can fix this? Maybe I can get the Ip address of the drive somehow and use it instead?

thanks for you help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just check if that network drive is ready.
There's a [DriveInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.driveinfo.isready(v=vs.110).aspx) class in the .NET Framework which indicates if a drive is ready (if a CD is inserted in a CD ROM device or if a removable storage is ready for IO, which also applies to network drives).

I've quickly tested this with a small PowerShell script to verify this and this is my output:

```
Name               : Y:\
DriveType          : Network
DriveFormat        : 
IsReady            : False
AvailableFreeSpace : 
TotalFreeSpace     : 
TotalSize          : 
RootDirectory      : Y:\
VolumeLabel        : 

Name               : Z:\
DriveType          : Network
DriveFormat        : HGFS
IsReady            : True
AvailableFreeSpace : 420309352448
TotalFreeSpace     : 420309352448
TotalSize          : 500105736192
RootDirectory      : Z:\
VolumeLabel        : Shared Folders
```

You can use the example given in the MSDN documentation to write the code for your application which could look like this (didn't test yet but should work):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class MyClass {
    public bool CheckNetworkDrive(String name) {
        bool result = false;
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo d in drives) {
            if (d.Name == name) {
                result = d.IsReady;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [net use](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx) to find IP or Computer Name of mapped network drive

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c net use";
process.Start();
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();


var line = output.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Where(x => x.Contains("U:")).FirstOrDefault();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
{
    var host = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("\\"), line.Substring(line.IndexOf("\\")).IndexOf(" ")).Split(new[]{'\\'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).FirstOrDefault();
    Ping pinger = new Ping();
    PingReply reply = pinger.Send(host);
}
```